# Suma de la diagonal principal y secundaria de una matriz

Tags: c++

Se debe imprimir en una línea la suma de todos los elementos de la diagonal principal y la diagonal secundaria de la matriz. NOTA: Tome en cuenta que para una matriz que tiene una cantidad n impar de renglones y columnas, hay un elemento exactamente al centro de la matriz, y por ese motivo pertenece a ambas diagonales, en este caso, para el resultado de la suma solo se acumula una vez dicho número.

¿Cómo implemento la suma de la diagonal secundaria, sumando una sola vez el numero de en medio?

Este es mi codigo, debo utilizar la biblioteca #include <stdio.h>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int MATRIZ[TAM][TAM];                                                                                        
    int m,renglon,columna;
    int SUMADIAGONALPRINCIPALYSECUNDARIA;
    scanf ("%d",&m);
    
    for(renglon=0;renglon<m;renglon++){
        for(columna=0;columna<m;columna++){
            scanf ("%d", &MATRIZ[renglon][columna]);
        }
    }
    SUMADIAGONALPRINCIPALYSECUNDARIA=0;
    for(renglon=0;renglon<m;renglon++){
        SUMADIAGONALPRINCIPALYSECUNDARIA=SUMADIAGONALPRINCIPALYSECUNDARIA+MATRIZ[renglon][2-renglon];
    }
    printf ("%d", SUMADIAGONALPRINCIPALYSECUNDARIA);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto no es lo mismo que publicaste en tu otra pregunta?

Comment: _¿Cómo implemento la suma de la diagonal secundaria, sumando una sola vez el numero de en medio?_: Simplemente lo restas no? de la suma `a + 2b + c`, obtener `a + b + c = a + 2b + c - b`

Answer (score 2):

Como indiqué en el comentario de la pregunta, se puede hacer simplemente restando el valor de en medio.

Supongamos que en la matriz 3x3 de los números del 1 al 9, en la diagonal principal están los números `1, 5, 9`, y en la secundaria están `3, 5, 7`, el `5` se repite en las dos, ya sea que hagamos un `if` para verificar si ya se sumó esa posición de la matriz, o simplemente recordemos un poco de aritmética y restemos el valor de en medio `1 + 5 + 9 + 3 + 5 + 7 - 5 = 1 + 5 + 9 + 3 + 7`. Creo que esto es lo más sencillo (por lo menos para mí).

El código a continuación hace exactamente eso, asumiendo que la matriz es cuadrada

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    int matrix[n][n] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };

    /*int n = 4;
    int matrix[n][n] = {
        {1,     2,      3,       4},
        {5,     6,      7,      8},
        {9,     10,     11,     12},
        {13,    14,     15,     13}
    };*/

    int total_sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                     // main diag   // second diag
        total_sum += matrix[i][i] + matrix[i][n - 1 - i];

    if (n % 2 == 1) // checar si hay que restar el valor de en medio
        total_sum -= matrix[n / 2][n / 2];

    std::cout << total_sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Si lo ejecutas verás que el resultado es `25 = 1 + 5 + 9 + 3 + 7`, lo cual es correcto.